# how to create selection in a "CircleAvatar?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm creating an app where the user can choose up to three avatars, my question is how do I make the avatars have the following state: when selected, they have a blue border and the text changes to gray (not selected) to black when selected?

Below is an image of the avatar when selected. //////////

vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv

[image]

o cod:

```
body: GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {},
    child: Center(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                child: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: Color(0xfff3e0a6),
                  radius: 30.0,
                  backgroundImage: AssetImage('image/person.jpg'),
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                      radius: 12.0,
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.camera_alt,
                        size: 12.0,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                child: Text(
                  'avatar1'
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 20,),
          Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                child: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: Color(0xfff3e0a6),
                  radius: 30.0,
                  backgroundImage: AssetImage('image/person.jpg'),
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                      radius: 12.0,
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.camera_alt,
                        size: 12.0,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                child: Text(
                    'avatar1'
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 20,),
          Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                child: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: Color(0xfff3e0a6),
                  radius: 30.0,
                  backgroundImage: AssetImage('image/person.jpg'),
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                      radius: 12.0,
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.camera_alt,
                        size: 12.0,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                child: Text(
                    'avatar1'
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 1):

use text and color as variable to your avatar, then set onTap inside GestureDetector to set the color and text. and call setstate

Comment: and how do you do? lol